# Custom UIColor for Label

Tags: iphone, ios, text, label, uicolor

I want to create a custom color for my labels. Looking for a darker green than what is given.

The code I have is below:

```
switch()
{
    case0:
        [answerLabel0 setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        break;
    case1:
       [answerLabel1 setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
       break;
    case2:
       [answerLabel2 setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
       break;
    case3:
       [answerLabel3 setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
       break;

    default:
       break;
}
```

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `[UIColor colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha]` method

for example:

`[UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.8 blue:0.5 alpha:1.0]`

note that the rgb values are from 0 to 1, not 0 to 255.

Answer (score 3):

**If you want to color in RGB**

You could create four colors as to your own specifications before the switch statement and then use them within. *Take note, the colors you make are RGB colors with an additional alpha (transparency) value. You will have to determine these values yourself.*

```
UIColor *color1 = [UIColor colorWithRed:(255.0/255.0) green:(255.0/255.0) blue:(255.0/255.0) alpha:(100.0/100.0)];
UIColor *color2 = [UIColor colorWithRed:(255.0/255.0) green:(255.0/255.0) blue:(255.0/255.0) alpha:(100.0/100.0)];
UIColor *color3 = [UIColor colorWithRed:(255.0/255.0) green:(255.0/255.0) blue:(255.0/255.0) alpha:(100.0/100.0)];
UIColor *color4 = [UIColor colorWithRed:(255.0/255.0) green:(255.0/255.0) blue:(255.0/255.0) alpha:(100.0/100.0)];

switch(variable){ 
  case 0: 
    [answerLabel0 setTextColor:color1]; 
    break; 
  case 1: 
    [answerLabel1 setTextColor:color2]; 
    break; 
   case 2: 
    [answerLabel2 setTextColor:color3]; 
    break; 
   case 3: 
    [answerLabel3 setTextColor:color4]; 
    break;
   default: 
     break; 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a UIColor in several ways. Refer to http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html for more information.

You can declare a custom UIColor for green as follows:

```
UIColor *greenColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.000 green:0.331 blue:0.000 alpha:1.000];
```

Then, you can use that color in your conditional as follows:

```
[answerLabel2 setTextColor:greenColor];
```